# Bigcommerce change price dynamically depending on customizations

Tags: bigcommerce

On Bigcommerce, Is it possible to change the price dynamically depending on what customizations the user chooses? Is it also possible to let the user select a "package" of customizations.

For example if a customer chooses the "gold" package of a product, which is a very specific combination of customizations of the product, is it possible to apply it without defining that specific product variation in the backoffice, and change the price accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please let me know if I'm misunderstanding your question. But I believe product variants are what you're needing to set up here. In your control panel, you can add variations (for example 'tiers') of your product with different pricing levels. These will be nested under the product. You can set up inventory tracking in the control panel as well. Inventory tracking can be placed on the product or variant level.

You can create a single product variant here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/product-variant-options/createoption

If you need to make more than one variant on a product, you can use this endpoint instead: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/products/createproduct

On the other hand, if you're not wanting to do this with variants rather with product customizations -- you can still set the price, but you'd have to set rules for this instead.